# Question concerning a correspondence between basis elements of the Schur algebra and some matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, representation-theory

I have the following question:

Let $k$ be an infinite field and let $S_k(n,r):={A_k(n,r)}^{∗}=\text{Hom}_k(A_k(n,r),k)$ and $A:=A_k(n):=\text{polynomial functions on}\  \Gamma:=\text{GL}_n(k)$ and

$A_k(n,r):=$ the subspace of $A$ consisting of the elements expressible as polynomials homogeneous of degree $r$. Thus, $S_k(n,r)$ is "the Schur algebra".

Now, let $r=n=2$.

Let $I:=\{ (i_1,i_2)\ |\ i_1,i_2\in \{1,2\} \}$ bet the set of all maps from $\{1,2\}$ to $\{1,2\}$

and let the symmetric group $\Sigma_2$ act on $I$ from the right by place permutation and on $I \times I$ from the right by $(i,j)\pi:=((i)\pi, (j)\pi)$. This gives 10 different $\Sigma_2$-orbits.

In the book "Schur algebras and representation theory" of S. Martin on page 34 we see an example.

Each orbit gives rise to a corresponding basis element.

Now my question is:

> How do we get the correspondences
>
> $\xi_{(12),(21)}\leftrightarrow \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},\  \xi_{(11),(22)}\leftrightarrow \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},\  \xi_{(12),(12)}\leftrightarrow \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\ ?$
>
> For example, where does the $1$ in the upper right corner of the second matrix come from?

Thanks for the help!